# RegEx to prohibit some special characters

Tags: regex

What is the proper regular expression to exclude or prohibit

> < > * % : & \

I am trying

> ^[^<>*%:&\\]$

but that does not seem to work. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct for single characters. If you want to validate longer strings,

```
^[^<>*%:&\\]*$
```

if empty strings are okay, or if not,

```
^[^<>*%:&\\]+$
```